# How to set the view and preview links in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress in "/wpengine". However, the wordpress is integrated into a login protected portion of a non wordpress based site under "/community".

Authors will not have access to the password protected portion of the site, but they may need to preview pages and posts.

My question is this. How can I set the preview and view links in the admin section to '/wpengine', without changing the site address under settings (which is set to /community now).

*Basically I want all the blog links to point to /community and all view and preview links in the admin to point to /wpengine*

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: So the address of your WP site is: `myfoobarbaz.com/community/wpengine` ?

Comment: Wordpress is installed in myfoobarbaz.com/wpengine (WordPress address in settings)
The site address (where all the links point to) is myfoobarbaz.com/community (Site address in settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Im not sure if this is proper WordPress etiquette, but I added the following into the wp-config file.

```
if(false !== strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin')){
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://myfoobarbaz.com/wpengine');
    define('WP_HOME',    'http://myfoobarbaz.com/wpengine');    
}
```

Now when a user is in the admin section, WordPress points all links to /wpengine instead of /community